# Why do I get Unity instead of Classic when using NX?

Tags: 11.04, unity, freenx

Recently I installed FreeNX on my PC and when I login with my 'dev' account I get the Unity interface rather than Classic Gnome. This is odd as my last login before FreeNX was with the Classic interface. I would like to have Classic over FreeNX by default.

I do login with a 'watch iplayer' account where the Unity interface works a treat. For this reason I would prefer not to uninstall Unity.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Example for nomachine's NXClient:

Under 'desktop'

select 'unix' in the first drop down menu.
select 'custom' in the second drop down menu
click 'settings' on the right of it.
choose 'Run the following command' and insert:

```
gnome-session --session=2d-gnome
-or-
gnome-session --session=classic-gnome
```

and choose the 'New virtual desktop' option.

[image: NX Client Configuration dialogue]

By default your system should have these 'sessions'

```
ubuntu
ubuntu-2d
2d-gnome
gnome
classic-gnome
```

ie, you could use gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d for a 2d Unity session (no effects)

Session files sit under

```
/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/

/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/2d-gnome.session
/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu-2d.session
/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/classic-gnome.session
/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome.session
/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu.session
```

Note:
'2d-gnome' and 'classic-gnome' look the same, I don't know if they differ anywhere in partituclar.

Comment: @DMB - you star for writing such a good answer. I could not find that elsewhere online and certainly not so well explained. Thankyou.

Comment: `Note: '2d-gnome' and 'classic-gnome' look the same, I don't know if they differ anywhere in partituclar.` - seems that 2d-gnome launches classic with the 2d Unity sidebar too, for this to crash and burn 'unexpectedly' shortly after session start, probably explaining why the two sessions 'look the same'. Needless to say I am on 'classic-gnome'.

Comment: interesting, I never managed to see that on my end ;) it probably crashes too fast, heh

Comment: Thanks for this, my session was failing to load with no helpful error message until I switched to `ubuntu-2d`. Odd that your Unity 2D is called `2d-ubuntu`. I've got `gdm`, `gnome`, `ubuntu`, `ubuntu-2d`.

Comment: These suggestions bypassed Unity but each panel opened in a separate window. Using the instructions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11586915&postcount=8) gave me a single window.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can just set `COMMAND_START_GNOME` in `/etc/nxserver/node.conf`

```
COMMAND_START_GNOME='/usr/bin/nx-session-launcher-suid gnome-session --session=classic-gnome'
```

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 the name of Gnome session classic is `gnome-classic` and the file that you must edit is `/usr/NX/etc/node.conf`.

Now, to start `gnome-classic`, edit `/usr/NX/etc/node.conf` and set `COMMAND_START_GNOME` to:

```
COMMAND_START_GNOME='gnome-session --session=gnome-classic'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
clear
#
#
# ubuntu server 12.04 freenx install script
# 
#
#
sleep 8
sudo apt-get update
#
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties
#
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team -y
#
sudo apt-get update
#
sudo apt-get install freenx -y
#
wget https://bugs.launchpad.net/freenx-server/+bug/576359/+attachment/1378450/+files/nxsetup.tar.gz
#
tar xvf nxsetup.tar.gz
#
sudo cp nxsetup /usr/lib/nx
#
sudo /usr/lib/nx/nxsetup --install
#
echo -e "\n#Use classic gnome for client sessions\nCOMMAND_START_GNOME='gnome-session --session=classic-gnome'"|sudo tee -a /etc/nxserver/node.conf
clear
#
#
#
# Done!
#
#
sleep 8
```

Comment: I've fixed the formatting (in terms of the way it appears here; I didn't change the text of the script itself). The way to post large blocks of code is to paste it into your question or answer, select it, and click the `<$>` icon in the AskUbuntu editing toolbar. (If you wanted to do it with pure HTML rather than markdown--which I am not recommending, unless you have a specific reason you need that--then you could enclose the text between `<pre><code>` and `</code></pre>`.) **Also, you should edit your answer to include some kind of explanation for exactly what this does and how to use it.**

Answer (score 0):

In my case was more useful the following option

```
COMMAND_START_GNOME="/etc/X11/Xsession 'gnome-session --session=gnome'"
```

This let you run the NX client as a window and you can set the window properties directly with the NX gui.