# Use Unity on Console and Unity 2D on FreeNX?

Tags: unity, 11.10, unity-2d, freenx, nx

I love freenx and I am having great difficulty trying to get it to work on an 11.10 server. When I try to connect, I immediately get disconnected. I have seen in posts that Unity 3D causes issues with nx sessions. I can SSH to the machine.

Is there a way I can keep the standard 11.10 Unity on the console, but force nxserver to use Unity 2D?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get Unity instead of Classic when using NX?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/50503/why-do-i-get-unity-instead-of-classic-when-using-nx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is here:

[Why do I get Unity instead of Classic when using NX?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50503/why-do-i-get-unity-instead-of-classic-when-using-nx)

[This question should redirect to that one]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a installer script, which compile and install freenx server on Ubuntu 11.10. Works with Unity 2D.

See my blog post: http://notepad2.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/install-freenx-server-on-ubuntu-1110.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.