# problems doing remote admin via ssh

Tags: 10.04, ssh

I am connected to an Ubuntu host (10.04.3 LTS) via ssh -X. All is ok. However, I cannot do any administrative tasks via System->Administration->xxx, such as adding a User, because the system never asks me for a password, and ignores any change requests I have.
If however I go to the host and log-in conventionally, everything works as expected.
In other words, the system discriminates me when I am logged-in via ssh. Where's the trick?
Tx Luis

Answer (score 1):

This is how it (policyKit) is supposed to work.

It can be changed, but it's not as easy as it should.

There is good [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/54053/211) here, in a different question. To summarize it you will need to create a new policikit configuration file that allows remote users to do administrative task using the GUI. In the above answer there is a script that will create that file.

Comment: If you find this question helpful, please vote for enzobit for the original answer, insightful answer that is not receiving the votes that it deserves.